# out of memory when using .asJson in big object

Tags: scala, circe

I use scala, circe.
I have an object that contains very big list.
what i already tried: when i encode it to json it leads to out of memory.
Is there a solution how can i proceed using iterators, akka reactive streams ?

Comment: How are you sending this `JSON` out to the client?

Comment: have you modified the heap size for the scala code in any way from the default, if not you could try this java -Xmx512m -Xms256m -jar your_scala_app.jar -

Comment: This sets the maximum heap size to 512 megabytes and the initial heap size to 256 megabytes. Adjust these values based on the requirements of your application.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez i want to save this json into file and this file is a response of rest call

Comment: @AnandSatheesh yes this heap size is changed4

Comment: Sure, how are you writing the json to a file? Which technology are you using? Also, why to a file and then serve the response? Is the file reused?

Answer (score 0):

You can process encoding/decoding JSON or any other computation on a large collection using any streaming library, such as Akka Streams, depending on the technology stack used in your project.

Here is an example how to encode data to JSON with circe(version 0.14.5) and Akka Streams(version 2.8.0):

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import io.circe.Json
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._

object CirceParseBigCollection extends scala.App {
  case class MyData(field1: String, field2: Int)

  val bigList = LazyList.from(1).take(100000).map { i =>
    MyData(s"item-$i", i)
  }

  implicit val system: ActorSystem                           = ActorSystem()
  implicit val ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher

  // Create an encoder for MyData
  val source = Source(bigList)

  val flow = Flow[MyData].map { obj =>
    val json = obj.asJson
    Thread.sleep(100) // any additional computations here
    json
  }

  val sink = Sink.foreach[Json](json => println(json))

  source.via(flow).to(sink).run()

}
```